# Drupal Multisite (subdomain) Not Working

Tags: 6, multi-sites

Drupal 6, default installation, default .htaccess, default http.conf for Apache.

`sites/` directory looked like this:

```
all
default
subdomain1.maindomain.com
```

`default` site and `subdomain1` working well.

Added a new directory, `subdomain2.maindomain.com`. It has the same ownership and permissions as `subdomain1.maindomain.com`. It contains `default.settings.php`, the out-of-the-box one, and `settings.php`, which is a copy of `default.settings.php`. The permissions and ownership of the two files are correct.

The 'sites' directory now looks like this:

```
all
default
subdomain1.maindomain.com
subdomain2.maindomain.com
```

Visiting `subdomain2.maindomain.com` returns an error. Visiting `subdomain2.maindomain.com/install.php` returns an error. I can download an example file from  `maindomain.com/sites/subdomain2.maindomain.com/files/example.txt` when it is located at `/sites/subdomain2.maindomain.com/files/example.txt`.

Basically, I've followed all the steps in the docs, and I'm unable to create another 'subsite' accessible from a new subdomain. What am I doing wrong? What else should I be doing?

Comment: What exact error does subdomain2.maindomain.com return?

Comment: 'Connection has timed out'. hmm....

Comment: I think you have a DNS issue and/or an Apache config issue.  dig subdomain2.maindomain.com and make sure it points to the right place.  Then watch the request with Firefox Live HTTP Headers and see what is happening.  Then check the Apache access and error logs and try to match everything up.

Comment: You just create new subdomain2.maindomain.com domain that have code base from your main default drupal site. If you run at local you must input new line in hosts file to make it works

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run several sub-domains on the same code base you need to make sure that either both the sub-domains resolve to the same IP address as your main domain, or that your main domain supports wildcard DNS. You also might consider giving [Subdomain](http://drupal.org/project/subdomain) module and [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module a try.

Answer (score 0):

Check that subdomain2.maindomain.com should point to the same directory as is subdomain1.maindomain.com in the cpanel. This directory is the root of Drupal installation.

Firstly simply create a symbolic link ( ln -s subdomain1.maindomain.com  subdomain2.maindomain.com ) and see if the subdomain2 is accessible. Otherwise it is configuration issue with Apache/Cpanel.